# Include directory in WAR using Ant

Tags: ant

I am building a war file using ANT and I want to include the src directory into the war file. When I use the fileset element, only the content of that folder is included. I want the src directory to be included into the WEB-INF folder. I don't want to copy the sources to the WEB-INF folder on disk. Ant properly includes the jars from my lib directory into `WEB-INF/lib` without copying them in my project.

So I will have something like this:

```
/WEB-INF
/WEB-INF/src
/WEB-INF/classes
/WEB-INF/lib
/META-INF
```

The target looks like this:

```
<target name="war" depends="init">
    <war destfile="dist/web.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
        <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        <lib dir="lib"/>
        <classes dir="build/classes"/>
        <classes dir="config"/>
    </war>
</target>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you were trying to include src something like this:

```
<fileset dir="src"/>
```

It should work if you use this:

```
<fileset dir="." includes="src/**"/>
```

If you need to put a file or dir to a specific path in the war, you can use [zipfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) instead and its prefix attribute, e.g.

```
<zipfileset dir="." includes="src/**" prefix="WEB-INF"/>
```

(See also examples in the [war task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html), which include usage of zipfileset).

Comment: Thanks, we're half way there. Now the 'src' folder is in the root of the WAR. Is there a way to get it into WEB-INF?

Comment: you could do a copy of your *src* folder in the dist folder and them include.

Comment: @udeleng, if you wanna place some folder/files into WEB-INF, just do it that way: <zipfileset dir="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/tmp/uploads" prefix="WEB-INF/tmp/uploads" />